# Why isn't the input valid as a JSON-string C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, parsing, httpclient

I am working on an ASP.NET application and I am sending a request (REST API) in my class library. I have a test application (Console Application) where the same code works perfectly without any error but goes wrong in the ASP.NET application of our customer.

I do the following in the test application:

```
using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL))
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    //headers
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenResponse.AccessToken);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    RequestObject createdRequest = CreateRequest();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createdRequest);

    StringContent stringContent =
        new StringContent(
            json,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");

    //body (content) of the request
    request.Content = stringContent;

    //sending the request through a POST method asynchronously
    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        string stringContents = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

I am running the same piece of code in the ASP.NET application but receiving a statuscode `BadRequest` and at `string stringContents = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` it says: The provided input is not valid as a JSON-string and cannot be parsed.

The following JSON object is what I print out with `Console.WriteLine();` (I've left a number of properties due to privacy):

```json
{
  "MainObject":[
    {
      "Object1":{
        "prop1":"value",
        "prop2":"value",
        "prop3":"value",
        "prop4":"value",
        "prop5":"value",
        "prop6":"2018-09-20"
      },
      "Object2":{
        "prop1":"2822",
        "prop2":null,
        "prop3":100.0,
        "prop4":"value",
        "prop5":"value",
        "prop6":"value",
        "prop7":"value",
        "prop8":null,
        "prop9":null,
        "prop10":null,
        "prop12":null,
        "prop13":null,
        "prop14":null,
        "prop15":2,
        "prop16":0.0,
        "prop17":0.0,
        "prop18":"value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?